# Vaadin: error when trying to load add-on

Tags: java, maven, widget, vaadin, add-on

I am developing an application in Java using Maven and Vaadin 6 for some time now.

I've come to a point where I need to add an add-on (Vaadin calendar 1.3.0 - for Vaadin6).

I've added the maven dependency and repository in my pom.xml file as suggested on the link attached, Maven did download my dependency jar file and it is in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

However, when I try to load the page with the add-on I get the following error message (in browser):

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.addon.calendar.ui.Calendar. Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:
```

From what I understood the widget set is not compiled. But I do not know how to do this...
I tried to install the Vaadin-plugin in Eclipse. It says on their website that when the vaadin plugin detects a widgetset in the path, it is automatically compiled.
I've also tried to follow the tutorial for using vaadin addons, but still no luck: http://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons

Did you run into similar problems? What should I do? How do I compile the widget set?
Some useful tips please? :)

Your help is very appreciated.

---

UPDATE: I've tried to follow the steps from this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/addons.maven.html

now whenever I try to load the application I get the following error:

Failed to load the widgetset:
/myproj/VAADIN/widgetsets/...../TheNewFileCreatedAsInTutorial.nocache.js

Answer (score 0):

If you already have installed the eclipse vaadin plugin, try compiling manually as described in section [16.2.2](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html).